# GROUP BY column A or column B

Tags: group-by, union

I have a table with 2 columns (ref1, ref2) referring to another table. I am looking for a SELECT query to generate a summary of how often values in ref1 or ref2 exist, counting twice if a value is in both columns:

```
SELECT ref1,ref2 from table;
(100,100),
(100,101),
(100,NULL)
```

Should lead to:

```
(100,4),
(101,1)
```

The only approach I can think of is a UNION, but I hope there is another way. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`union` removes duplicates, so that won't work - you need the `union all` operator:

```
SELECT ref, COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT ref1 AS ref FROM mytable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ref2 AS ref FROM mytable) t
```